# Undelete a question?

Tags: support, status-completed

I accidentally deleted my question 'Where did the tradition of Christmas come from', and would like it undeleted. I thought that I should have done more research first, so then I remade it and wanted to post an answer, so I remade it, but the system is telling me that it is a duplicate and I cannot undelete the original question because I don't have 10k reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has been undeleted.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it.